# How to set additional environment variables for new process in typed-process?

Tags: haskell, process, typed-process

I'd like a new process to inherit the existing environment variables, as well as set my own.

I only see two options to set the environment variables within http://hackage.haskell.org/package/typed-process-0.2.6.0/docs/System-Process-Typed.html:

```
setEnv :: [(String, String)] -> ProcessConfig stdin stdout stderr -> ProcessConfig stdin stdout stderrSource
setEnvInherit :: ProcessConfig stdin stdout stderr -> ProcessConfig stdin stdout stderr
```

I could manually get a list of all environment variables with `System.Environment.getEnvironment` however it's documentation(http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getEnvironment) mentions:

> getEnvironment retrieves the entire environment as a list of
>   (key,value) pairs.
>
> If an environment entry does not contain an '=' character, the key is
>   the whole entry and the value is the empty string.

Which seems a bit iffy.

---

Looking through the source there seems to be a data constructor that has the environment variables set in `pcEnv :: !(Maybe [(String, String)])` - but this does not seem to be exported. Is there some means to modify this value?

Comment: The POSIX spec *defines* the environment as a list of strings consisting of a name and a value joined by `=`. `getEnvironment` simply ensures that an entry like `foo` is treated like the "proper" entry `foo=`.

Comment: Also, `pcEnv` won't help here.  It's the configuration option that's *set* by `setEnv` (set to `Just` an environment) and `setEnvInherit` (set to `Nothing`).  Your solution of using `getEnvironment` and adding additional options to the result is the correct way of doing what you want to do, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround can be done using the `unix` package:

```
import System.Posix.Env (getEnvironment)

currentEnv <- getEnvironment
let totalEnv = currentEnv ++ [("KUBECONFIG","k8s.cfg")]
```